# Does this sentence grammatically make sense?

Tags: commas

I found some sentences and don't know if they have correct form of grammar. I might not understand grammar well.

I got this from " The Kite runner"

228p
She stood beaming under a dull gray sky, tears streaming down her cheeks, the needle-cold wind blowing her hair, and clutching the baby in her arms like she never wanted to let go.

I thought that phrases between commas should refer to she as subject of the phrases.

==> and clutching the baby in her arms like she never wanted to let go.
This one, the meaningful subject is "she"

However,
==> tears streaming down her cheeks, the needle-cold wind blowing her hair

these just depict the situation not referring to she as subject.

340 p

I heard the officer, his voice tired and uninterested, asking his obligatory questions.

==> his voice tired and uninterested
This one refers to the officer.

==> asking his obligatory questions.
This one refers to I

Is it possible when you write one sentence? each phrase connected to commas can refer to different things?

Thank you for your advice in advance.

Comment: In the first example *she* and *her* are referring to the same person. In the second example both uses of *his* are referring to the officer.

Comment: For example, "asking his obligatory questions" does not refer to *I*: The officer *was* asking his obligatory questions.

Comment: Khaled Hosseini is a respected writer; it's not likely his editor would let him get away with ungrammatical sentences.

Comment: The first example *could* have proceeded as *She stood beaming under a dull gray sky, **laden with moisture after travelling over hundreds of miles of ocean***. It's *semantics* rather than *syntax* that tells us my highlighted clause refers to "a dull gray 
 sky", not "she".